# Click on MS Office document from Sharepoint and will open Office, but not document

Tags: microsoft-office, sharepoint

After I open Sharepoint inside IE, and click on a Word/Excel/PP document, it opens the proper MS Office application, but does not open the file itself.

The file can be opened from inside of office.

Comment: Which versions of SharePoint and Office are you using?

Different versions have different levels of compatability

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft [Hotfix KB Article Number: 949405](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/949405)

Installed on client machine, worked like a charm!